# Javascript ES6 (React) How to use a method of an imported class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

Using javascript ES6 (React), I'm not able to call a simple method of an imported class.

What's wrong with this code?

> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__Seed**.a.test is not a
>   function

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import Seed from './Seed';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('start1');
    Seed.test();
  }

  render() {
    return("ei");
  }

}

export default App;
```

and

```
// Seed.js
import React from 'react';

class Seed extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('seed1');
  }

  test() {
    console.log('seed test');
  }

};

export default Seed;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few options, depending on what you're trying to do

1) If this function is unrelated to an instance of a Seed, then make it static.

```
class Seed extends React.Component {
  static test() {
    console.log('seed test');
  }
  // ...etc
}
```

Then you can call it the way you're already calling it.

2) If it needs to be tied to a specific instance of a seed, you could new one up and then  call it. For example:

```
const mySeed = new Seed();
mySeed.test();
```

Given that Seed is a react component this is very likely **not** what you want to do, since you should let react do the instantiating of components and then interact with it through props

3) Use refs to let react give you a reference to the component. I'll assume you're using react 16 or higher and thus have access to React.createRef

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.seedRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.seedRef.current.test();
}

render() {
  return <Seed ref={this.seedRef}/>
}
```

This is better, but its still questionable that you would want to interact with a component this directly.

4) Use props, don't call it directly. Exactly how to do this depends what you're trying to do, but suppose you want to only call the method if some condition is true. Then you could pass a prop in to the Seed, and the seed calls the method itself.

```
// in App:

render() {
  render <Seed shouldDoStuff={true} />
}

// In seed:

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  if (props.shouldDoStuff) {
    this.test();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very complete answer. I've seen that I can also access to the method "indirectly" by setting the method as a getter (without declaring it as static). Could you please comment on that in your answer? Thanks again :)

Comment: What is it you want to know about getters? They will be on the instance, not on the class, so they'll be very similar to bullet points 2-4

Comment: If I write "get test() {...}" then I can access to Seed.test and execute the code inside the method. It is another way to execute the method I mean

Comment: Getters are typically used to hide the fact that there's a function involved, but if you want to use one you can. As i said though, it will be on the instance, not the class. `Seed.test` will not work; `(new Seed()).test` will

Comment: Yes, you're right. Somehow the Seed.test with the getter appeared to work a few minutes ago, but I cannot reproduce it now so ... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with declare test as static like this

```
class Seed extends React.Component {

  static test() {
    console.log('seed test');
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('seed1');
  }

};
```

if you want call `test` in Seed component use `Seed.test()`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access a class' method like that since it's not [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).

You would need to have `App` render with a `<Seed />` and get a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html) to that component.

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import Seed from './Seed';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('start1');
    this.seedRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // seedRef is the Seed instance
    this.seedRef.current.test();
  }

  render() {
    return(<Seed ref={this.seedRef} />);
  }
}

export default App;
```